# Show Wordpress posts in chronological order categorized in years

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, sorting

I want to sort my posts by year. Following code works almost perfectly. 
But the current year (2017) is displayed multiple times although the other years are displayed just once (how it is supposed to be). I don't understand the logic behind this. Thanks for your help!
 
**2017**
— Post 6
**2017**
— Post 5
**2016**
— Post 4
— Post 3
**2015**
— Post 2
— Post 1

*code updated, but still same problem.

```
    <?php

    $starting_year = date('Y');
    $ending_year = 2010;

        while ($starting_year > $ending_year):

                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'ausstellungen', 'posts_per_page' => 99999, 'cat' => 6, 'year' => $starting_year );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );?>

                <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

                        <a class="lesetypo medium"><?php the_date('Y');?></a>

                        <li>
                            <?php while ($year =! $year): ?>
                                <div class="hide">
                                <?php $slug =  $post->post_name;?>
                                <p><a href="<?php echo $slug ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php endwhile;?>
                        </li>

                <?php endwhile;

        $starting_year--;

        endwhile;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi, I have updated your code snippet, please go through the below code**

```
  $starting_year = date('Y');
    $ending_year = 2010;

        while ($starting_year > $ending_year):

          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'ausstellungen', 'posts_per_page' => 99999, 'cat' => 9, 'year' => $starting_year );
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );?>
               <a class="lesetypo medium"><?php echo $starting_year;?></a>
                <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                        <li>
                            <?php while ($year =! $year): ?>
                                <div class="hide">
                                <?php $slug =  $post->post_name;?>
                                <p><a href="<?php echo $slug ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php endwhile;?>
                        </li>


                <?php endwhile;

        $starting_year--;

        endwhile;
```

Comment: A good answer provides and explanation as well as code. It's difficult to see what's changed and why as it is.

Comment: I called $starting_year variable outside the 2nd while loop instead of calling the_date('Y') inside the 2nd while loop